# Laravel Variable Not Passing Through

Tags: php, laravel

I'm an absolute beginner and I'm trying to do a CRUD in Laravel, but I can not figure it out why my variables aren't being passed over to the view so I can have a dynamic display of them in the table.

My "routes" work fine.

Then my controller

```
     public function getHome()
     {

     $results = Crud::index();
     return view('pages/home', ['results' => $results]);

     }
```

Calls my "Crud" model

```
class Crud extends Model
{
     public static function index()
     {

        return $results = DB::table('data')
                         ->whereNotNull('id')
                          ->get();
     }
}
```

And goes to my view as seen in the controller

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| Home')

@section('content')

 <div class="container">

     @include ('partials/_jumbotron')

     <table class="table table-inverse">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>


 @if(!empty($results))

  @foreach($results as $result)

  <tr>
    <td scope="row">$result->$id</th>
    <td>$result->$first_name</td>
    <td>$result->$last_name</td>
    <td>$result->$username</td>
  </tr>

@endforeach

 @endif

</tbody>
</table>
</div>

 @endsection
```

Thanks for the help in advance...I'm losing my mind
And sorry If I wasn't specific enough..

Edit1: I did as you say, but I'm still not outputing data to my table? Is there anything else wrong in the stated code or is the bug somewhere deeper?

Edit2: Thanks everyone for the pointed out mistakes - blade {{ }} and object properties
$object->propertie not $object->$propertie

When I fixed those mistakes which were obviously denying the output I remembered that I have an empty database.. Case Closed - Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Try using `$result->first_name` and repeat for the other fields. Notice there’s no $ after the arrow. Those are not variables, they are properties of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not printing the variables. You're printing literals.

If you want to print the variables (`echo` them) in blade files, you need to [wrap them in curly brackets](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data). Also there's not `$` when you want to display an object attribute. Like that:

```
@foreach($results as $result)

<tr>
    <td scope="row">{{ $result->id }}</th>
    <td>{{ $result->first_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $result->last_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $result->username }}</td>
</tr>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner too, I thought maybe you might want to try this as well

```
public function getHome()
{
     $results = Crud::index();
     return view('pages/home', compact('results'));
}
```

But before anything else make sure if your code is actually returning your data from DB using

```
dd($results)
```

Answer (score -1):

The first of all cleaner will be using laravel *with* function for example

```
return view('pages/home')->with('results', $results);
```

Next you try to get $result->$first_name it didint working becouse first_name is not variable, laravel return object so you can get first_name like that:

```
{{$result->first_name}}
```